# Bounty reminder emails should not be sent when question has no answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

If the question does not have any answers, this email should not be sent:

> Reminder: Your Bounty Is Ending Soon!
>
> Your bounty on the question …
>
> … ends in 23 hours.
>
> Don't forget to review the answers and
>   award your bounty by clicking the
>   bounty indicator to the left of each
>   answer. If you don't award your
>   bounty, the highest scored answer
>   (with a minimum of 2 score) provided
>   after your bounty started may be
>   automatically  awarded half the bounty
>   amount!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the problem is not that the email is sent, it is the text itself.

> Reminder: Your Bounty Is Ending Soon!
>
> Your bounty on the question …
>
> … ends in 23 hours.
>
> Don't forget to review **any** answers and **update your question with anything new you've learned**. When you find the right answer, you can award your bounty by clicking the bounty indicator to the left of each answer. If you don't award your bounty, the highest scored answer (with a minimum of 2 score) provided after your bounty started may be automatically awarded half the bounty amount!
>
> [Bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: +1 But, how about a *different* email text if there are no answers?

Comment: @MarkJ, my suggestion is based on the implicit assumption that it is easier to edit the text of the individual email, rather than add extra logic and an extra email template. Obviously, if they want to undertake that, they could.

Comment: I expect your implicit assumption is correct, I wanted to make sure the idea of a different email was considered.

Comment: @MarkJ `But how about a different email text if there are no answers` Request completed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139356/147645

Comment: @JimmyPena Great! Took just under 2 years... Must... Not... Grumble... :)

Comment: @MarkJ Just a timing issue I guess ...

Answer (score 3):

Good idea; this is completed per

[Why encourage bounty awarding when there are no answers at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139356/why-encourage-bounty-awarding-when-there-are-no-answers-at-all)