# In the bounty reminder email, don't suggest me to improve my question if it has a positive score

Tags: feature-request, bounties, email, email-notification, score

A week ago I started a bounty on my question [How can I bundle my tests which use Sinon.js using Rollup.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40334243/3853934) Now the bounty has ended, but I haven't received any answers. I got an email saying this:

> Thanks for putting a bounty on your question. It looks like there are still no answers yet. You should consider improving your question to attract more answers. Could you:
>
> - add more text describing the problem?
> - add or change the tags?
> - update the title to more accurately reflect the issue?

Generally, it's reasonable to ask the user to improve their question, but in my case my question already has 8 upvotes and no downvotes, which is a strong indication that my question doesn't need any improvement, and the only reason that I haven't received any answers is because nobody who visited it knew the answer.

Related: [Why encourage bounty awarding when there are no answers at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139356/310998).

Comment: Why are you taking offense to the suggestion it might stilll be possible to improve your question? You want me to list at least three things you can do to improve your question?  (don't worry I won't) but your question can be improved :-)

Comment: @Ramhound I am not offended by that suggestion; I just think that it's not helpful.

Comment: It's a suggestion, by an automated system, sent out to all users with a bounty for questions that recieved no new answers.  As I said before your question can be improved so you should accept the suggestion actually was helpful.  The only answer you did receive, was a comment ask for a example, submitted as an answer.  I suggest next time next time, just be more open to feedback, when you offer a bounty to a question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of improving a question includes adding more relevant information to it.

Let's say you might have asked your question last week.  Four days go by, and you've been working on it continuously.  You've tried a few solutions, but none of them have worked.  You decide to put a bounty on your question to get more attention.

At this point, your question can be improved, *even if it was perfect and upvoted many times at its inception*, by adding details about what you have tried and why they didn't work.  That saves bounty hunters the wasted effort of suggesting these as possible answers.

I'd wager the majority of bounty offerors don't do this. A helpful reminder that they should consider improving their questions at this time seems like a good idea, upvoted or not.

Answer (score 1):

I am yet to see a question that could not be improved.

If your question currently has 8 upvotes and no downvotes then it suggests that your question is well written.

However, it has not received any answers, even with a bounty, and as its asker I think you must bear some responsibility for your question not being answered.

I think that message reminds you that you may need to try and make your question more answerable by editing it, to perhaps clarify aspects that may make it look like it is harder to answer than it is, or perhaps *even to relax or alter what you will accept in the way of an answer*.

On a Q&A site I think all askers should not just ask questions but also help to get them answered.

Even if you see no way to improve your question I think it is reasonable for the bounty process to suggest that you *might* be able to.

Comment: I have done my best to make my question answerable. I haven't received any answers probably because there are very few Rollup.js experts on Stack Overflow (the [rollupjs] tag has only 5 followers and 65 questions).